# if exists not working in batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm using if exist for checking the existence of a file. If I run the batch from the same directory where the file is, it is ok. But I need to ru the batch from another dir so I put an absolute filename but then the batch fails  with two messages: 
File Not Found
( was unexpected at this time

the statement I'm trying is the following:

```
if not exist F:\IBM\PCImport\filename*.csv (
   echo file does not exist 
)
```

Comment: This statement should give no problem - but the error message indicates that this is not the complete story. Please post a larger section of the code so we can see it in-context.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your posted example or the answer already given. Please update your question with the code you have decided to omit if you wish to receive further positive help with your issue.

Comment: Is `F:` a mapped drive letter to a UNC path?  Are you running an elevated command prompt? Is UAC enabled?  I doubt any of these are the problem but just covering all bases.  We really need to see all of your code as Magoo already stated. Your error is begin caused by something you are not showing us.

Answer (score 0):

`EXIST` only checks if files exist. There are a few system/hidden files Windows uses in its file system. Try the following:

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\Documents and Settings\NUL" (
    echo it exists
    Pause
) else (
    echo Folder not found
    Pause
)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, but also without the "not" it is not working.